# How to get (x, y) coordinates from sql convexhull

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

How can I extract the x,y coordinates from the result of this query?
I have tried many variations but none of them have worked correctly.

```
select * --This row should contain something like t.ch...x
from (select sdo_aggr_convexhull (
     sdoaggrtype (
       sdo_geometry(2001, NULL, sdo_point_type(x, y,  NULL), NULL, NULL),
       0.5
     ) 
   ) ch
from table1 where name = '111') t
;
```

wrong result:

```
SDO_AGGR_CONVEXHULL(SDOAGGRTYPE(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,NULL,SDO_POINT_TYPE(X,Y,NULL),NULL,NULL),0.5))    
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,null,null,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(x1,y1,x2,y2))
```

should be something like:

```
x1     y1

x2     y2

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following syntax:

```
select x,y
from table (
  select sdo_util.getvertices( 
           sdo_aggr_convexhull (
             sdoaggrtype (
               sdo_geometry(2001, NULL, sdo_point_type(x, y,  NULL), NULL, NULL),
               0.5
             ) 
           )
         )
  from table1 
  where name = '111'
)
order by id;
```

The sdo_util.getvertices function extracts the coordinates from the ordinate array and casts them into an array. The TABLE() construct then flattens the array into a regular table. Each vertex also contains an ID attribute that you can use to order them in the proper sequence they appear inside the polygon.